# Override tkinter entry widget insert method to achieve transliteration in python

Tags: python-3.7, tkinter-entry

## Aim:

I want to achieve transliteration in python tkinter entry widget where user will type in english and it will get typed in hindi, marathi or whatever language user selects.

## What I did:

I created my custom entry class which has few custom features like validations, placeholders etc.
What I want is to implement transliteration in the class. transliteration. I have already implemented the method that will provide me the translated text.
Following is the code what I tried.

```
def translator(value):
    # my logic
    return new_value

class MyEntry(tk.Entry):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.placeholder = kwargs.pop("placeholder", "")
        self.required = kwargs.pop("required", '')
        self.translate = kwargs.pop("translate", False)

        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)

        self.default_fg_color = self['fg']
        self.placeholder_color = 'grey'

        self.insert("end", self.placeholder)
        self['fg'] = self.placeholder_color
        self.bind("<FocusIn>", self.remove_placeholder)
        self.bind("<FocusOut>", self.focus_out_event)

    def insert(self, index, value):
        if self.translate == True and not self.placeholder:
            value = translator(value)
        super().insert(index, value)

    ### rest of the code
```

## Issue

The insert method is not triggering when user starts typing. I wanted it to be class's default functionality so that user will only pass the attribute when using the widget.
like `MyEntry(root, translate=True)`